# Ubuntuにおいてapt updateができない

Tags: ubuntu, apt

## 環境

ホストOS：Windows 11 Pro
ゲストOS：Ubuntu 22.04.1
仮想環境：VMware Workstation 16 Player（ネットワーク接続はNAT）

## 問題点

以下のupdateコマンド実行時にエラーが発生しています。

```
sudo apt update
```

エラーメッセージ

```
ヒット:1 http://archive.ubuntulinux.jp/ubuntu jammy InRelease
ヒット:2 http://archive.ubuntulinux.jp/ubuntu-ja-non-free jammy InRelease      
ヒット:3 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease               
ヒット:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
ヒット:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease              
ヒット:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease            
ヒット:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease             
無視:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/f-muriana/ubuntu-builder/ubuntu jammy InRelease
エラー:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/f-muriana/ubuntu-builder/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了                 
W: http://archive.ubuntulinux.jp/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: http://archive.ubuntulinux.jp/ubuntu-ja-non-free/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
E: リポジトリ https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/f-muriana/ubuntu-builder/ubuntu jammy Release には Release ファイルがありません。
N: このようなリポジトリから更新を安全に行うことができないので、デフォルトでは更新が無効になっています。
N: リポジトリの作成とユーザ設定の詳細は、apt-secure(8) man ページを参照してください。
```

下から3行分で何やら対策のことを示されていますが、何をしていいのかわかりません。

## 試したこと

1. `sudo apt install (パッケージ)` でのインストールは正常に実行できました。
2. `ping 185.125.190.52` では応答があります。
3. Webブラウザではインターネットに正常に接続されているようです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### エラーから調べたこと

エラーに出ている "このようなリポジトリから更新を安全に行うことができない" をキーワードに検索するだけでも多数のページがヒットし、apt のリポジトリ設定に問題がありそうだという事が分かります。

該当リポジトリは [ubuntu-builder](https://launchpad.net/%7Ef-muriana/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntu-builder) を提供していたようですが、更新が2014年で止まっており、パッケージの最新版も "12.10 (Quantal Quetzal)" 向けになっています。

#### 対処方法

`/etc/apt/sources.list` または `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` 配下のファイルから `https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/f-muriana/ubuntu-builder/ubuntu` の記述を削除してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。/etc/apt/sources.list.d/内に、f-muriana-...という名前から始まるファイルが二つあり、その中身をコメントアウトすることで、updateでエラーが出ることはなくなりました。